# how to select the specific value from UIpickerView

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that iam using the picker view with 10 values.Whenever i scroll the picker to down,after picker stooping last values will be selected and did selectrow will be fired.But i don't want that one,i need to select which one i want to select.So please tell me how to do that one.

Answer (score 0):

There is `UIPickerViewDelegate` Method which gives you the selected row:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        float rate = [[exchangeRates objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
        float dollars = [dollarText.text floatValue];
        float result = dollars * rate;

        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"%.2f USD = %.2f %@", dollars, result,
               [countryNames objectAtIndex:row]];
        resultLabel.text = resultString;
}
```

This could be proper link [Click here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example) for your question.

Comment: May be u can't undestand my question.If i scroll the picker then above method will be fired and pick the one value.But i dont need that one.And i dont need that automatic value selection.